# ResolveUrl prepending random string to actual url

Tags: c#, url, resolveurl

I am using `resolveUrl` to call a virtual directory specified in my `web config`. Recently my error log gave me a issue to where it prepened a long string to this path. So to be clear it resolved the proper `url` but added a string that was over 240 chars long. I am wondering if anyone has ever had an issue with this.

Here is the call:

```
string originalImage = ResolveUrl(m_photoVirtualPath) + "/" + table.Rows[0]["Key"].ToString() + "/" + table.Rows[0]["LargeImageFileName"].ToString();
```

Here is the output error:

> (F(7teHGa3jtAWTm0cKjtcKe8aKQMb99ykEWnc2c8L7RGHP28aRwzXYDhA8vWHRepIqFN67FGtHRN41v3kiseUsbMoNZqUDgS9h7g8acMSFRDPTYxbM3UA2pUXAUzWJcCWU4A3oVlFz6YoAqXVCAGNJiGbUiWdjcsREGNAkdQHkzX6SjCf12QonsibppUVPiean-saajTAzQjgoRK1qnFactg2))**/storage-pub/Photo**/2901502/40719_19760_2903337.jpg

the `/storage-pub/Photo` is the correct resolved `url` shown in bold above and the directories after are also correct but I have no idea what the string is before the resolved `url`.

Comment: Are you using cookieless sessions?

Comment: No were are not using cookieless sessions. The odd part of this all is 99.9% of the time this works just fine.

Comment: @MikeC it turns out it maybe cookieless what where you thinking could be the issue. I would like explore this avenue as nothing else has turned up anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out after some debugging that it was the cookie string that was getting pre-appended to the URL. Still not sure as to why or how it happened but by using the tracing features in vs2010 I was able to view all my cookie and session strings and from there I was able to compare them to the string in the URL. Thank you all for your help and guidance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `Server.MapPath`

```
string originalImage = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(m_photoVirtualPath) , table.Rows[0]["Key"].ToString() , table.Rows[0]["LargeImageFileName"].ToString());
```

Comment: I could but there is no reason that I would need the absolute path not only that but it is a virtual directory so it would not lead me to the correct location. Correct me if my thinking is wrong. Plus I am resolving the location just fine just not sure about the prepended string. Is it something IIS does when something going wrong etc.

Comment: you need relative path in order to bring flexibility, in you deploy your package

Comment: Server.MapPath would return me a absolute location. Maybe it would help if I gave you more context. This is for a url redirection for instance http://_url_/Handler/Handler.ashx?Mode=Sepia&ImgSrc=/storage-pub/Photo/2901502/40719_19760_2903337.jpg. Therefore an absolute path returned for sever.mappath would be useless.